# Convert String of datetime(201004301342) into Datetime value(103 Format)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I Have a string like as given below

201004301342

Need to convert it into dd/mm/yy format

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will change the value to a datetime. A datetime has no format until you convert back to a string again.

You can use `stuff` to change the string value to `20100430 13:42` and then cast to datetime.

```
declare @Date varchar(12)

set @Date='201004301342'

select cast(stuff(stuff(@Date, 11, 0, ':'), 9, 0, ' ') as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a string and start string is always with this format then

```
declare @date varchar(50)
set @date = '201004301342'
SELECT convert(varchar, cast(substring(@date, 1, 8) as datetime), 103)
```

Comment: Thanks for you too for converting it to 103